# How to allow selecting text behind an absolutely positioned element, without using pointer-events:none

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, z-index

I have an HTML table with some text, where every row of the table should also be functions a link.

I do this by adding an absolutely positioned anchor element inside the `<tr>`, which has `position: relative`. This works very nicely, but the absolutely positioned `<a>` prevents the user from being able to select the underlying text to copy it to the clipboard.

I found a few answers suggesting adding `pointer-events: none` to the top element, which indeed works in the sense that the text underneath is selectable, but then this element stops reacting to all click events, and the link doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work?
Here's a simple version of my code, also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeLrm6cn/1/)

```html
  <table>
 <tbody> 
    <tr style="position: relative">
      <td>
        <a style="position: absolute; inset: 0; -webkit-user-drag: none;" href="#"></a>
        I want</td>
      <td>to be able</td>
      <td>to select this text</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr style="position: relative">
      <td>
        <a style="position: absolute; inset: 0; -webkit-user-drag: none; pointer-events: none" href="#"></a>
        This text is selectable </td>
      <td>but then the link</td>
      <td>doesn't work</td> 
   </tr>
 </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Why do you use a link button? Why don't you add event listener to the `tr` without adding invisible anchor tag?

Comment: @Konrad Hmm this is indeed a good question. I don't have a very good reason, I guess. I can say that I do like the link behavior, where I can see the URL in the browser corner while hovering over the link.
But also, semantically I guess this is more "correct", in a way - It's really a link which spans the entire row. It would be more correct with screen readers, bots and such. But maybe it doesn't outweigh in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you introduce an anchor tag, you lose the ability to select the anchor text mid-way (you can still select the text if you begin the text selection prior to the start of the link).

Therefore, to allow mid-text selection, you need to detect a click, but reject the click if the mouse moves enough that it looks like text selection rather than a click.

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("tdlink")].forEach(e=>{
  let clickStart = {x:0,y:0};
  e.onmousedown = e=> Object.assign(clickStart,{x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY});
  e.onclick = e=> Math.max(Math.abs(clickStart.x-e.clientX), Math.abs(clickStart.y-e.clientY))<3 && (Object.assign(clickStart,{x:0, y:0}), document.location.href = e.target.dataset.href);
})
```

```css
.tdlink {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody> 
    <tr style="position: relative">
      <td class="tdlink" data-href="https://wikipedia.org">The quick brown fox</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
<table>
```